# How do I debug a web-page if there's some script running into stuck?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I have developed a web page with more than 10 external javascript dependencies.

The web page will load a file (via AJAX) and do some work.

However, when the page loads a file, the page got stuck totally. I can't find any abnormal stuff in the file, so it must be some script problem. But since the page got stuck, I can't locate the error location.

How can I do with my Chrome DevTools to locate the error?

Comment: use breakpoints and examine the values of variables

Comment: what if the page got stuck at first even before I can set up breakpoints?

Comment: set the breakpoints and click refresh